# ASP.NET MVC 2 How to check the user's permissions before action is executed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a controller, and to invoke all its actions the user has to have privilages to do that. The question is how to check that before action is executed? **If the user doesn't have permissions I want to render a View with error message.** I tried to use overriden `OnActionExecuting` method, but I can't return a View from that method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to use overriden OnActionExecuting method, but I can't return a View from that method

As a matter of fact you can:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    bool userHasPermissions = CheckUserPermissionsFromSomewhere(filterContext);
    if (!userHasPermissions)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            // you can also specify master page and view model
            ViewName = "Forbidden"
        };
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! :) I'm also wondering how to create a 'base' method which will be rendering a view with error messages (the message will be used as a parameter). Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In the class Controller this method is protected.